# How to set location with extension in NGINX server

Tags: nginx, path, location

I'm new with NGINX server and I was wondering how to set something like this.

```
location phpmyadmin \.(gif|jpg|png)$ {
    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
}
```

example above fails at server restart.

Thanks for all answers.

UPDATE:

```
location ~* .(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|3gp|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|flv|mp3|mid|js|css|html|htm|wml)$ {
    root /home/safeftp/www/public_html;
}

location ~ "phpmyadmin \.(gif|jpg|png)$" {
    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use regex, use `~` (for case-sensitive matching) or `~*` (for case-insensitive matching). Your location block should look like this:

```
location ~ "phpmyadmin \.(gif|jpg|png)$" {
    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
}
```

You can read more here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: Hi, thank you for help but this one doesn't work. I actually need regular expression to match this: /phpmyadmin/whatever/path/to/some/picture.png

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong it works pretty well, but I found another problem. How can I use these two locations simultaneously? ps. check updated post

Comment: Here is the regex I would use: `^/phpmyadmin/.*\.(gif|jpg|png)$`

Also, keep in mind that regular expressions are checked in order of their appearance. If you want a location to take precedence over another, try swapping the order.